# Regular expression which splits the strings and numbers with decimal

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Eg : `var letter = $46.68666;`

splits this $letter as

```
     letter[0]=$
     letter[1]=46.68666
```

IN Jquery use:

```
$reslut= letter.match(regxp).slice(2);
```

Comment: Why slice(2)? What's your question?

Comment: i want to split the letters and numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to slice;

```
var letter = "$46.68666";
var result = letter.match(/^(\${1})(.*)$/).slice(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

`/^(.)(.*)$/` maybe? it just picks the first character... you haven't defined if it needs to be any smarter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression:

```
/^(\D?)(\d+(?:|\.\d+))$/
```

It will match similar strings as given below:

1. $46.68666
2. $46
3. 46.68666
4. 46

`$1` variable from regex match will either be empty/null or will contain `$`. `$2` variable from regex match will contain the number with decimal.